# Simple censor function does not work in python

Tags: python, function, if-statement

I have created a function that takes a text and a word to censor in the text. It should return the text but with the censor word replaced with ****. 
But it does not censor the word.

```
def censor(text,word):
  if word in text:
    word="*"*len(word)
  return text
```

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: You don't alter `text`. Try using [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not making any changes to the string 'text'. The example code below should give you the desired output.

```
def censor(text,word):
  if word in text:
    text= text.replace(word,"*"*len(word))
  return text
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't impact on `text` varible. You should replace your code to

```py
def censor(text,word):
  return text.replace(word, "*" * len(word)) # -> it will replace word to * if word in text else it will do nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the value in the original text, modifying the iteration variable won't have any effect, try this:

```
def censor(text, word):
    return text.replace(word, '*' * len(word))
```

Also it's not necessary to check if the word is in the text, if it's not the replace operation will do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution, without the `replace()` method, if you want something similar:

```
def censor(text,word):
    censor_block = '*'*len(word) 
    text_words = text.split(' ')
    return ' '.join(
        [text_word if text_word != word else censor_block for text_word in text_words]
        )
```

You need to split the text into words, then you need to iterate over those words and if you find the given word, you need to replace it with `censor_block`. Finally, you need to join the list of words into a text and return it. With a for loop, you need to use indexes, because a string is non-mutable. Instead of this, I used a list comprehension.

In place of `text_word` and `censor_block`, you can use functions instead, handling more complex tasks.

```
[f(x) if condition else g(x) for x in sequence]
[f(x) for x in sequence if condition]
[f(x) for x in sequence]
```

These will work.

Hope it helps :)